# better understand of NSURLConnection with NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue, sendasynchronousrequest

I make a queue

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

I send the queue to my async request

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // ... do stuff here
    });
}];
```

I cancel my operations prematurely

```
[operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

However, I can see my async's "completion" code still running. How come this scenario doesn't work like I expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it your responsibility to check `isCancelled` during your operation's task in case it gets canceled halfway though?

NSOperationQueue won't just kill tasks, it will set them as cancelled and let them finish themselves. This lets you clean up any resources you might have allocated and tidy up before you exit.

Tasks that haven't started yet won't start.

Comment: How can I check `isCancelled` from within my block? I don't have a reference to the operation and `self` has already been "nullified" by this point because I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in my block when `self` is accessed.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's a problem. Though surely your completion handler will already be on the main thread so you don't need the god at all?

Comment: "don't need the god at all" I'm not sure what you mean.. Sounds too religious for this convo :)

Comment: Thanks autocorrect! What I meant was you won't need gcd at all!

Answer (score 1):

`cancelAllOperations` goes through the items in the queue and calls `cancel` on each one. If you look at the documentation for `completionBlock`:

> The completion block you provide is executed when the value returned by the isFinished method changes to YES. Thus, this block is executed by the operation object after the operation’s primary task is finished or cancelled.

can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

edit:

another snippet from the documentation for `setCompletionBlock:`

> A finished operation may finish either because it was cancelled or because it successfully completed its task. You should take that fact into account when writing your block code. Similarly, you should not make any assumptions about the successful completion of dependent operations, which may themselves have been cancelled.